# Jquery collect form data and send to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code:

```
var data = [];
var workerEdit = {
    'id':'',
    'name': '',
    'photo': '',
    'bibliography': '',
    'history': '',
    'salary': ''
}
workerEdit.id = ""+id+"",
workerEdit.name = $('#workers_response input[name="name"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]').val(),
workerEdit.photo = $('#workers_response input[name="pas-scan"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]')[0].files[0],
workerEdit.bibliography = $('#workers_response textarea[name="bibliography"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]').val(),
workerEdit.history = $('#workers_response textarea[name="history"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]').val(),
workerEdit.salary = $('#workers_response input[name="salary"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]').val()
data.push(workerEdit);
```

How i can convert my data var to FormData and send it to php throw ajax?

Comment: Create One Object and post that object to PHP now in your case you just need to send workerEdit serializeArray()

Comment: why don't use you use jQuery  `serialize()` or `serializeArray()` to do this?

Comment: so what was the problem and how to send you share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var data = {
  'id':'1',
  'name': '2',
  'photo': '3',
  'bibliography': '4',
  'history': '5',
  'salary': '6'
};
var formData= new FormData();
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  formData.append(key, data[key]);
})
for(var part of formData.entries()){
  console.log(`key: ${part[0]}, value: ${part[1]}`);
}
```

`Object.keys(@object)` will return a array with key of the object you pass. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys